# Is there something similar to SUSE Studio but geared toward Debian-based distros?

Tags: debian, distribution-choice

I am playing around with SUSE Studio and am finding it quite amazing, though (I imagine for sentimental reasons) I prefer Debian and the deb package manager.

Is there something like SUSE Studio that is based on Debian?

That is to say, is there something web-based like the SUSE Studio site with which you can build your own Debian image?

Comment: It might be helpful if you'd elaborate on which aspects of SUSE Studio you like... there probably is no *"Debian Studio"* ([anymore](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/studio.debian.net)), but maybe some of SUSE Studio's possibilities can be realised (e.g. [building a live image](http://live-build.debian.net/cgi-bin/live-build)).

Comment: Thanks, you have steered me in the right direction. Updating my question now...